Is it possible to set ACL permissions for Boost.Interprocess managed_shared_memory? If not, how can I achieve this?
I'm using the Boost.Interprocess library in C++ to manage shared memory using the managed_shared_memory class. I am creating the shared memory segment with the open_or_create flag and specifying permissions. I am using ubuntu.
My questions are:
Can ACL permissions be set directly using Boost.Interprocess when creating a managed_shared_memory segment? I am unable to find any information or documentation on setting ACLs directly within Boost.Interprocess.
I know that traditional Unix permissions can be passed to the constructor of shared memory. But I am looking for more fine grained access control. I want to set ACL permissions for the file when it is being created, as in my program I want to pass a list of users who can access the file, and the program should create shared memory with these permissions. If Boost.Interprocess does not support setting ACLs directly, what is the recommended approach for managing ACL permissions for shared memory? Is it practical to use system calls or external commands to set ACLs after creating the shared memory segment, or is there a better approach?
Any insights or best practices for handling ACL permissions with Boost.Interprocess would be very helpful.

You can pass a permissions object to the constructor to specify your ACL - see Named Resource Permissions. The permissions constructor takes a os_permissions_type, which is an alias for SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* on windows.

@Turtlefight please consider making that an answer for the sake of information sharing; answers are much more easily found than comments (in fact, comments are all but discarded for most purposes)
